# Filter in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have the following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>      
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?person a foaf:Person;
  foaf:name ?name;
  prop:deathCause ?death_cause.
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?name), "EN")) .
}
LIMIT 50
```

If you run this here: http://dbpedia.org/snorql/

You will see that you get a lot of results. Now I would like to filter out one death cause, let's say 'Traffic collision'. So this should be simply by adding a filter:

```
FILTER (?death_cause = "Traffic collision").
```

So the query should then be:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>      
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?person a foaf:Person;
  foaf:name ?name;
  prop:deathCause ?death_cause.
  FILTER (?death_cause = "Traffic collision").
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?name), "EN")) .
}
LIMIT 50
```

However this returns nothing. Anyone that knows what is wrong with the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You will see that you get a lot of results. Now I would like to filter
>   out one death cause, let's say 'Traffic collision'. So this should be
>   simply by adding a filter:
>
> ```
> FILTER (?death_cause = "Traffic collision" ).
> ```

Filters define what things you *keep*, not what things you remove, so if you wanted to filter *out* traffic collisions, you'd actually want:

```
FILTER ( ?death_cause != "Traffic collision" )
```

If you try that, though, you'll still see traffic collisions in your results, because there's a difference between `"Traffic collision"` and `"Traffic collision"@en`.  The former (which is what your code would be removing) is a plain literal (i.e., without a datatype or a language tag).  The latter is a literal with the language tag `"en"`.  These are *not* the same, so filtering out one doesn't filter out the other, and keeping one won't keep the other.  To remove the `"Traffic collision"@en`, you can filter it out with:

```
FILTER ( ?death_cause != "Traffic collision"@en )
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`str`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) function to get the lexical part of a literal, so you could filter out `"Traffic collision"` regardless of the language tag (or datatype, if it appeared as a typed literal):

```
FILTER ( str(?death_cause) != "Traffic collision" )
```

Thus:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX type: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>      
PREFIX prop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?person a foaf:Person;
  foaf:name ?name;
  prop:deathCause ?death_cause.
  FILTER (langMatches(lang(?name), "EN")) .
  FILTER ( ?death_cause != "Traffic collision"@en )
}
LIMIT 50
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20type%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/class/yago/%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0APREFIX%20prop%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%2a%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?person%20a%20foaf%3aPerson;%0D%0A%20%20foaf%3aname%20?name;%0D%0A%20%20prop%3adeathCause%20?death_cause.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28?name%29,%20%22EN%22%29%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%20?death_cause%20!=%20%22Traffic%20collision%22@en%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2050&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I actually didn't mean _filter out_, I wanted a single death cause. But removing the "!" in the last query in your answer solves that and learning to filter _out_ I consider a bonus! A small follow-up: What is the reasoning behind adding str() around the property name/variable? That is not obvious.

Comment: @MariusLian Literals in RDF can be plain (no language or datatype), typed (with a datatype), or language tagged (with a language tag).  `str` extracts the string part from all three kinds.  I've added more explanation to the answer.

Comment: So actually in the other filter that is what happens. The lang() function extracts the language part. Thanks for a clear explanation!